# Computer Communication with HP Color Laserjet CP1515n

Tags: printing, printer, hp-laserjet

I have an HP Color LaserJet CP1515n. It prints a test page in full color when prompted to from the printer's own buttons, but it won't print from the computer. One time it printed a page, but every other time the computer tells me there is an error.

Frequently when I plug in the USB cable it says there was a problem installing the driver, but other times it says the driver was installed correctly.

The cable that I'm using was taken from another printer, and it was working with that printer.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I figured it out. It was a problem with the cable. A different cable works perfectly. For some reason the old cable wouldn't work consistently with this printer even though it was the right size.

Answer (score 0):

that's difficult to answer, you did not wrote which kind of OS you use.
The printer seems to be a network printer. Do you want to print via usb or via network.
It is important that the installed printer driver is configured with this kind of way (usb or network) you want to use this device.
You suggest you to remove the existing driver, download the driver from HP web site. Make the printer available via usb or network and reinstall the driver.
If you use network, you must know the IP address from the printer. And the printer must be reachable via ping.

ciao
ryder